# Front end [running in docker container] not able to access ASP.Net core API [running in another container]

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating two docker containers one front end and another one is .net core API. But when i call the API from the front end, I am getting an exception as follows,

> SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I have also added a docker compose file to enable multi-container deployment but of no use. This is yml file as follows,

```
services:
  dockerdemofrontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemofrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoFrontEnd/Dockerfile

  dockerdemoapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemoapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoAPI/Dockerfile
```

I am feeling like those two networks are different. We need to do something in order to get these two talking. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You definitely need a compose file (and start the containers using `docker-compose up`, not `docker run` on each container). Otherwise, they won't be on the same vnet. Assuming you're using `docker-compose` to run your containers, then they will all be on the same vnet and can see each other. How are you trying to connect to the API?

Answer (score 0):

you can assign one network to both services like

```
services:
  dockerdemofrontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemofrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoFrontEnd/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - common

  dockerdemoapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemoapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoAPI/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - common


networks:
  common:
    driver: bridge
```

and then your host will be name of service ex : dockerdemoapi and port will be port number at which your api is running internally

Comment: So you are saying add a property to docker compose file and then specify the port name which the API is running for both front end and api. In API, I see that the host and port are specified as {ServiceHost}:{ServiceApi}. So should I edit those fields and hardcore it?

Comment: you only need to mention ports in docker-compose when you want to expose it locally otherwise it's fine and where does  ${ServiceHost}:${ServiceApi} variables come from as i am node developer so may be they are environment variables in that case just verify they are getting correct values example dockerdemoapi:3000

Answer (score 0):

Use `depends_on` in front end service to make the api always loads first. also, add them both in the same network otherwise you can not refer to them by service name.

```
version: "3"
services:
  dockerdemofrontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemofrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoFrontEnd/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - dockerdemoapi
    networks:
      - shared 

  dockerdemoapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemoapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoAPI/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - shared 
networks:
  shared:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: 1) `depends_on` merely starts that container first; it doesn't ensure that it's actually up and running. For something like a frontend connecting to an API, start order doesn't matter anyways, as the connection isn't made on start, but in response to some request at a later point. 2) Docker Compose automatically adds all the services in the same network; you don't have to specify a network manually unless you need to customize it for some reason.